# calling another web api end point from IdentityServer4 using IHttpClientFactory in .Net Core

Tags: identityserver4

I am using IdeneityServer4 and i have another Web Api controller in the identityserver4 api project and it is protected using identityserver 4 [Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]. part of the authorization/authentication process, i need to call another web api (which does not exist in this identityserve4 api project) endpoint using IHttpClientFactory in .net core. i am getting 401 unauthorized error. if i call this different end point by passing a token it works but if i call it from the identityserver4 api it is not working. basically i am trying to do is
1. client (angular app) calls the identityserver4 api by passing credentials and get a token. (IT WoRKS)
2. client calls another end point (different web api controller) in identityserver4 api by passing token (IT WORKS).
in this end point i am trying to call another user notification api by passing the same token received and it is failing with 401. the notification api is also using the same identityserver4 for authorization.
3. if i just call the notification api separately by passing the token it works fine.

i do not see any examples calling another endpoint from identity server api. i see different web api controllers in the identity server 4 api

## I am getting the token using following code in the web api controller method Identityserver 4 api and passing that token and required params to the SendUserInvitation method and its failing.

```
string bearerToken = null;
            if (Request != null && Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                bearerToken = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            }
```

======================================================================

```
public static async Task<bool> SendUserInvitation(string endpoint, string bearerToken, User userDetails, IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory)
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", bearerToken);
            var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDetails));
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Content = httpContent;

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseContent) ? true : false;
        }
```

not sure why i am getting 401, the same token being passed to different endpoint but still getting 401.

Comment: I don't think you can / should reuse the token in this case. Are you familiar with [Extension Grants](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html)?

Comment: Your token is likely issued for particular audience (your api1) and scopes for that api1, so when you call api2 - it doesn't see as a valid audience for that token. I will second also that you should reuse token like that. It can kinda be considered hijacking.

Comment: Did you add the API scope to the client you are calling from?

Comment: i am using same scope for all APIs in our application and we are already passing the same token from other API to call another end point. only it is not working when i call it from the Identityserver Api.